# How to connect to elasticsearch server using rest client with IP address

Tags: java, scala, elasticsearch

Here is my code;  it's working fine

```
val client =Option (new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"))))
```

but I need use the IP address. For that I am doing this

```
val client =Option (new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("192.168.1.8", 9200, "http"))))
```

It's throwing

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:171)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:145)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

then here in the ES docs 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html
under network.host heading it says to do this 
network.host = 0.0.0.0 in elasticsearch.yml 
after doing this and starting the elasticsearch server becomes stop with these log

```
019-07-09T16:03:24,956][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda7)]], net usable_space [88.4gb], net total_space [141.7gb], types [ext4]
[2019-07-09T16:03:24,966][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] heap size [989.8mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2019-07-09T16:03:24,981][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] node name [sara-Inspiron-7773], node ID [RK754dxuRiiCZYeR5NwN-Q], cluster name [elasticsearch]
[2019-07-09T16:03:24,982][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] version[7.1.0], pid[21369], build[default/tar/606a173/2019-05-16T00:43:15.323135Z], OS[Linux/4.15.0-52-generic/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_181/25.181-b13]
[2019-07-09T16:03:24,983][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] JVM home [/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_181/jre]
[2019-07-09T16:03:24,983][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] JVM arguments [-Xms1g, -Xmx1g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-7504410747021569879, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -Xloggc:logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32, -XX:GCLogFileSize=64m, -Dio.netty.allocator.type=unpooled, -Des.path.home=/opt/ifkaar/elasticsearch-7.1.0, -Des.path.conf=/opt/ifkaar/elasticsearch-7.1.0/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=tar, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,370][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,370][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [analysis-common]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,371][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,371][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [ingest-geoip]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,371][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [ingest-user-agent]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,371][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,371][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,372][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,372][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [mapper-extras]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,372][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [parent-join]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,372][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [percolator]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,373][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [rank-eval]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,373][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [reindex]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,373][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [repository-url]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,373][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,374][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-ccr]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,374][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-core]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,374][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-deprecation]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,374][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-graph]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,375][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-ilm]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,375][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-logstash]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,375][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-ml]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,375][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-monitoring]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,375][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-rollup]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,375][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-security]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,376][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-sql]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,376][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] loaded module [x-pack-watcher]
[2019-07-09T16:03:26,376][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] no plugins loaded
[2019-07-09T16:03:29,570][INFO ][o.e.x.s.a.s.FileRolesStore] [sara-Inspiron-7773] parsed [0] roles from file [/opt/ifkaar/elasticsearch-7.1.0/config/roles.yml]
[2019-07-09T16:03:30,166][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [sara-Inspiron-7773] [controller/21466] [Main.cc@109] controller (64 bit): Version 7.1.0 (Build a8ee6de8087169) Copyright (c) 2019 Elasticsearch BV
[2019-07-09T16:03:30,537][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.Security
[2019-07-09T16:03:30,871][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,559][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] initialized
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,559][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] starting ...
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,673][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] publish_address {192.168.1.8:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,679][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] bound or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [3] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
[3]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,720][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] stopping ...
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,739][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] stopped
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,740][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] closing ...
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,754][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [sara-Inspiron-7773] closed
[2019-07-09T16:03:31,758][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [sara-Inspiron-7773] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
```

How can I fix these two issues? Please help.

Comment: Before you post, please at least ensure that you have checked your spelling, written "I" and not "i", and capitalized words at the beginning of sentences. It will make your posts much easier to read. I've edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread explains what is happening: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/problems-with-access-to-elasticsearch-form-outside-machine/172450/2

> The cluster coordination algorithm has changed in 7.0 234 and in order to be safe it requires some specific configuration. We relax that requirement (that is, we run in a less-safe mode) when you bind to localhost only, but if/when you change network.host we enforce that your configure the cluster safely.
>
> This is covered in the breaking changes documentation 576 for 7.0

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/breaking-changes-7.0.html#breaking_70_discovery_changes

So it looks like you have to make a lot of config changes if you want to run a dev Elasticsearch that binds other than to `localhost`. It might be easier to bind to `localhost` and tunnel it out using `ssh` or similar? GL